# Move and copy constructor

Tags: c++

Please help me understand. When implementing Class Abc (code below) should I provide both A and B constructors or C instead? Yeah, years ago it would copy the entire vector twice with C option, but heard urban legend that the modern c++ can automatically apply either reference or move whatever needed to avoid unnecessary copy. Is that actually real?

```cpp
class Def {
public:
    Def() { /* ... */ }
    Def(Def&&) { /* ... */ }
    Def(const Def&) { /* ... */ }
    Def& operator=(Def&&) { /* ... */ }
    Def& operator=(const Def&) { /* ... */ }
    // ...

private:
    // Lets assume we have something not trivially copyable here
    // Low cost to move, but hundreds of megabytes to copy
    char *content;
};

class Abc {
public:
    Abc(Def&& def): def(std::move(def)) {}  // A
    Abc(const Def& def): def(def) {} // B

    Abc(Def def): def(std::move(def)) {} // C

private:
    Def def;
};
```

So now in the example below - If I have C constructor only, will compiler find out to use reference? Or should I provide at least either B and C or A and B?

```cpp
void someFunction() {
    Def def;
    // Here we load entire file into def

    Abc abc(def); // reference is needed, right?
    // here we do something with abc

    // and here we do something with def again.
}
```

Comment: Don't underestimate the [Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero)'s ability to automatically generate the correct code for you when it can be applied (and it can in the example code given).

Comment: @user4581301 well, in the above example yes, indeed. But sometimes it is not a case. The question is for that special case - could could C replace A and B somehow, like in the answer below? I see there either sould be A and B or B and C to avoid unexpected copies, right?

Comment: "_// reference is needed, right?_" I really don't understand what you mean with that. `Abc abc(def);` calls the copy constructor exactly once, no matter which overload set you choose. In the case of only `C` there will be an additional move constructor call to construct the member from the constructor parameter.

Comment: Can anyone tell how this refer to the: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a simple implementation, you should use the *C* constructor. If you need maximum performance, use the *A* and *B* constructors.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Def{
    Def() { std::cout << "    init\n"; }
    Def(Def const&) { std::cout << "    copy\n"; }
    Def(Def&&) { std::cout << "    move\n"; }
};

class CallByValue {
public:
    CallByValue(Def def): def_(std::move(def)) {} // C

private:
    Def def_;
};

class CallByReference {
public:
    CallByReference(const Def& def): def_(def) {}       // A
    CallByReference(Def&& def): def_(std::move(def)) {} // B

private:
    Def def_;
};
```

With these classes, the difference can be analyzed nicely.

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << "CallByValue:\n";
    Def a;
    std::cout << "  l-value:\n";
    CallByValue a1(a);
    std::cout << "  r-value:\n";
    CallByValue a2(std::move(a));

    std::cout << "CallByReference:\n";
    Def b;
    std::cout << "  l-value:\n";
    CallByReference b1(b);
    std::cout << "  r-value:\n";
    CallByReference b2(std::move(b));
}
```

```
CallByValue:
    init
  l-value:
    copy
    move
  r-value:
    move
    move
CallByReference:
    init
  l-value:
    copy
  r-value:
    move
```

The *C* version uses call-by-value. The user decides whether the parameter `def` is initialized by copy or by move. Then the value is moved from `def` to the member variable `def_`. This produces an extra move. In many cases, this tradeoff of a bit of performance for a much simpler implementation is acceptable.

Comment: Clear enough. I probably see the point now. So, there is no automagical conversion to reference/move in case having only the copy by value constructor, right? If that is the case, you are eligible for the bounty!

Comment: @noonespecial Yes, there is no such automatic conversion. Scott Meyer's book "Effective Modern C++" helped me a lot to understand these basics. The book is a bit outdated, but still good enough. Today you can find many PDF copies of it on the internet. But I don't know if this is officially allowed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It should be `def(std::move(def))` for `C` as well. With that change `C` may make one extra move construction relative to `A` and `B`, but that shouldn't usually make a difference.

Even better is to not give `Abc` any constructors and have it be an aggregate instead. Then (guaranteed since C++17) there is no copy/move at all for prvalue initializers and only one copy/move for lvalue/xvalue initializers, the minimal amount possible. With `A` and `B` there is always exactly one copy/move for lvalues/rvalues (including prvalues). With the modified `C` there will be an extra move for lvalue and xvalue arguments.

With the proper change of `C`, none of the scenarios ever does two copies.

Comment: I like your answer. Thanks. However, if I have C constructor only then there is no way it would find out to use reference, right? So for optimal code I need at least B an C constructors? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @noonespecial The difference is not usually significant, except if you have very large types that are costly to move. Imagine you had multiple constructor arguments. Are you going to write overloads for all combinations or lvalue/rvalue references for each parameter?

Comment: Lets assume it is low cost to move but hundred of megabytes in copy... Would compiler find out somehow to use reference when no move is applicable?

Comment: @noonespecial I don't know what you mean. If moving is low cost, then `def(std::move(def))` is low cost. I am not sure what you mean with "_Would compiler find out somehow to use reference_".

Comment: I clarified the question with exact example. IMHO, only having A and B makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

If `B` or `C` constructors are not defined, copy will happen as constructor `C` accepts its parameters by value thus it will copy the provided object.
Regardless if the constructor is called by

```
Abc abc(def); // reference is needed, right?
```

or

```
Abc abc(std::move(def)); // reference is needed, right?
```

In the latter case `def` is converted to an rvalue reference type, which MAY be moved, but not necessarily. [See reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).